# Python Help, If and Else

Tags: python

I'm making a basic Palindrome Checker in python for a small project. I have searched around and found no answer to this.

I am using the following code near the end of the script:

```
if String1 == String2:
               print("Yes")
else:
               print("No")
```

I receive a syntax error when I run this code. String1 is the text entered by the user and String2 is the text in reverse, which I develop earlier. I am running Python 3.2.3

Thanks in advance

I am using String2 == String1[::-1] for my Palindrome check and the error I receive is 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Edit:
This is my exact code however I'm not exactly sure where to put else: I have tried it multiple times on both new lines and on the line before with no success. String1 in this instance is "racecar"

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, 07:15:24) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import easygui as eg
>>> String1 = eg.enterbox(msg="Enter a Word")
>>> String2 = String1[::-1]
>>> if String1 == String2:
    print("Yes")


Yes
>>> else:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: The code as posted (while using odd indentation) is valid.  Can you post the actual traceback?  Also, quick palindrome checking in Python:  `String1 == String1[::-1]`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the error that you get. The mistake is probably in how you reverse the string, show us that part too.

Comment: Not a python programmer, so this may be a dumb answer, but python enforces pretty strict rules on whitespace, doesn't it? Maybe thats the issue?

Comment: Please paste the _actual_ traceback you receive.  There's something you're not providing, because what you've shown us does _not_ demonstrate a syntax error.  Also, see my answer.

Comment: Sometimes the error occurs in this line if you failed to close a bracket ( somewhere above.

Comment: Best is to post the complete code that produces the syntax error.

Comment: Sorry about that, it should be ok now

Comment: When hit enter after print("Yes"), press backspace and write "else:" <Return>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `[::-1]` to check for palindromes should work like a charm:

```
>>> s1 = "This is a string."
>>> s2 = "racecar"
>>> s1 == s1[::-1]
False
>>> s2 == s2[::-1]
True
```

There's something in your code that you're not showing us.  You need to paste a larger code snippet, or the *actual* traceback you receive.

And, now to account for your pasted traceback - you did not indent the `print` command after the `if` statement.  Because the `if` clause ended immediately it makes no sense (syntax error) to provide an else.  Indentation is syntax in Python.  You need it to look like this:

```
if String1 == String1[::-1]:
  print("Yes")
else:
  print("No")
```

The spacing is *mandatory*.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(["No", "Yes"][string1 == string1[::-1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your basic problem is that you're trying to do all this at the interactive prompt. You can do it, but you need to pay extra attention to make sure Python interprets all your statements as part of the same block. Blank lines will be significant here; since you are putting a blank line before `else:`, Python thinks that you have ended your `if:` and that you're trying to use `else:` at the beginning of a block, and this is indeed a syntax error.

So until you understand the ropes, it's going to be a lot simpler if you just put your code in a file and run it from there. You can do this with IDLE (File > New, then F5 to run your code) or you can use about any text editor and run your code from a command window.

Answer (score 0):

After the line

```
if String1 == String2:
    print("Yes")
```

press Enter, then **press Backspace**, and just then write:

```
else:
```

press Enter agian, and write:

```
print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already accepted an answer, but I'd have written that like:

```
print 'Yes' if String1 == String2 else 'No'
```

which encapsulates a single concept (selecting between two possible answers) into a single line.